# Can you choose when to use your lower Base Attack Bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, fighter, statistics

I have a fighter level 10. She uses two-weapon fighting. With her BAB at 10/5, she has a total of 3 attacks during a full  round attack correct? Also does her off hand attack receive the BAB of 10? All of these of course have the associated penalties from fighting with two weapon.

Answer (score 6):

The question in your heading doesn't match the question(s) in the body.

The answer to the heading is, No, you don't choose.

The answer to the body is, Yes, you are correct.

- BAB 10/5 refers to the first and second attacks (with the primary weapon).
- The offhand gets a single attack, at BAB 10.
- As noted, penalties apply to the final Attack Bonus, for two-weapon fighting.

I'm assuming you *started* at this level, or the answer would have been clear from lower levels. 
ie, Fighter level 5: BAB 5. What does the offhand use? Well, it *must be* 5. 
Fighter level 6: BAB 6/1. Would the offhand suddenly get *worse*? No.

---

Also, see this quote from the Full Attack action (emphasis mine):

> If you get multiple attacks because your base attack bonus is high enough, you must make the attacks in order *from highest bonus to lowest.* If you are using two weapons, *you can strike with either weapon first.* If you are using a double weapon, you can strike with either part of the weapon first.

You have to order the attacks from highest BAB to lowest. If your offhand was at a lower BAB, it should *automatically* come after your primary. But it specifically states you can use *either* weapon first.

(References: From PF SRD: [Fighter class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter), [Two-weapon fighting rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting), [Full Attack action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Attack))

Comment: They weren't *strictly* necessary - your original answer did sufficiently address the question, and was correct. Providing references does makes it easier for someone who doesn't already know your answer is correct to verify whether it is, however, and also lets them know where to look for more information about the subject should they wish to learn more.